# CodeIgniter version 3.x: Loading "Session" library reports ini_set warining

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3.0.1 in a Wamp64 installation (PHP Ver 5.6.19, Apache 2.4.18) on a Windows Server 2012 R2.
When I have the line:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

in `autoload.php` I get the following error on startup of my application:

> ini_set() A session is active You cannot change the session module's
>   ini settings at this time. Filename: libraries/Session.php Line
>   Number: 313

If I take that line out of autoload.php and put the following line in the contructor function of the controllers that actually use the session data:

```
$this->load->library("Session")
```

I get the same error, but only when I start one of those controllers.

I have reviewed multiple answers to this question on stackoverflow:

- Do you have a session_start() in your php code: NO - I have searched every piece of code included in this project and there is no session_start() anywhere
- Do you have session.auto_start set equal to 0 (zero) in php.ini - YES

Neither of these answers solves my problem.

Session info is being written out to `C:\temp` on the server. I see the file is created when I start the controller that first loads the Session library so the web server seems to have write access to the `C:\temp` folder.

The other interesting thing is that I have no problem with the installation on my test server (Windows 7, php version 5.6.32)

Can anyone offer any suggestions? Thanks!

One more piece of information: This was an upgrade from 2.x to 3.0. I did delete the \system sub folder and replaced it with the V3 \system folder.

Comment: How CI manage your sessions ? DB or FS ? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers

Comment: @kip - Using the file system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found it.**

The issue was an Ajax library (Sijax) which external to Codeigniter instantiated an instance of the class so that the methods could be called via Ajax. The *new(class)* triggered loading the Session class again, which ran through the initialization and tried to create the session again.

I removed the autoload of the Session class, and moved loading it to the Classes that require it, checking first to see if the Class already exists before calling the loader.